# MySQL: Is it possible to list all tables with a modification date?

Tags: mysql, runtimemodification

Is it possible to list all tables in a given MySQL database with the modification date in the right side?

I am looking for something like

```
SHOW TABLES FROM MY_DATABASE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the tables with `information_schema.tables`

```
select table_name, 
       coalesce(update_time, create_time) as last_modified
from information_schema.tables
```

Comment: Only for MyISAM, though

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Strawberry: AFAIK, these columns (create_time/update_time) are mapped directly to file attributes on table data files. Since innodb by default stores all tables in one big file, I can't imagine how it would work. Even with file-per-table mode, those dates are not very reliable.

Comment: @juergen_d This new column presents some dates, but it seems to not correspond the last modification dates. I have just modified a table in my database inserting a new element and the date that arises in the right side is about a week ago.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I see (well, I think I do). Thanks for the explanation.